# SciLab how to solve a differential equation with different time parameters

Tags: parameters, ode, scilab

I am a newbie to Scilab and I just typed these following equations from a paper for my thesis.
It describes a certain ordinary differential equation with association of lac enzyme genes. We do want to plot the time against each enzyme product concentrations.

However, I realized that in the paper, the `dy(1)` arguments  is requiring different time vectors, say `tM`, and `dy(2)` another, say `tB`, and so on as the script.

How could you do it in Scilab then? Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
funcprot(0)
function dy = lac(t,y)
    dy(1)=   am*(1+K1+(exp(-mu*tM)*y(4))^n)/(K+K1*(exp(-mu*tM)*y(4))^n)+ gamma_o - delta_M*y(1);
    //y(3) y(4) y(5)
    dy(2)=ab*exp(-mu*tB)*y(1) - delta_B*y(2);
    dy(3)=al*y(5)*Le/(KLe+Le)- bl1*y(5)*y(3)/(KL1+y(3)) -bl1*y(5) *y(3)/(KL1+y(3)) - bl*y(2)*y(3)/(KL2+y(3)) - delta_L*y(3);
    dy(4)=aa*y(2)*y(3)/(KL+y(3)) -ba*y(4) /(KA+y(4))-  - delta_L*y(4);
    dy(5)=ap* y(1) *(exp(-mu*(tM+tP) )) - delta_P* y(5);    
endfunction
```

Comment: As far as I know, Scilab's `ode()` only inputs a single value for independent variable (e.g. time instant) at a time. You can, however, manipulate it inside your function as you wnat, like `tM = 2*t`, or `tB = t-5`, or whatever. Still, is it possible that you made a mistake interpreting the ODE in the said paper? Perhaps you could edit your question and show us the original equations, and refer the paper from which you copied it.

Comment: Hi Luis, thx for the suggestions , this is the paper 's address that i am referring to :  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1302849/    , there you can find in page 2 all the equations.

Comment: First, this question seems to be a case of [XY problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem): you actually want to learn how to solve Delay Differential Equations, not ODE with with different time parameters. But don't takes this badly, it's a really common mistake, even if you're not aware of it. `tM` and `tB` are acutally (I think) `t - tM` and `t - tB`, that is why it's called "delay".

Comment: I believe you can try solving this kind of problems using Scilab's [`odedc()`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.1/en_US/odedc.html) which solves ODEs using discrete and continuous parameters at the same time. I will not post an answer because I've never used it myself. The paper you refer uses MATLAB's `dde23`, but I don't like it because it's proprietary software. You may be interested in trying Python's [`pydelay`](http://pydelay.sourceforge.net/) or Julia's [DDE solver](http://docs.juliadiffeq.org/latest/solvers/dde_solve.html), which are both open-source.

Comment: Okay, now i have this edited:i have three dde now and try the odedc .    
 y0=[0.01 0.01 0.01]';
t0=0;
t=0:0.1:2000;
flag=1 
 //rho = 1 //%dynamics  of gene enzymes M B A
function dy =lac(t,y)
  dy(1)= am*(1+k1*(%e ^(-mu*tm  ) *y(3)(t-tm) )^n   )/  (k+k1*(%e ^(-mu*tm  ) *y(3)(t-tm)^n)) - gm*y(1)
 dy(2)=ab*(%e ^(-mu*tb ) *y(1) (t-tb) ) - gb*y(2)
 dy(3)=aa*y(2)-ga*y(4)

    
endfunction



y = odedc(y0,3,(tm, tb),t0,t,lac);    and the compiler keeps throwing the error ,"arg 1 and 6 must have equal dimensions".  What should i then change?Thx for suggestion.